# get variable from python into js

Tags: javascript, python, html

I'm creating an app that shows a webpage search according to a random word that is chosen by the program. I uploaded a dictionary into python to get a random word and now I want to put this word into the src= in my javascript code. What I need is some kind of placeholder that connects the 2 languages

Python

```
if request.method == 'GET':

    #create an empty dictionary
    d = {}

    key = 0

    #open dictionary file and store it in 'dic'
    with open('dictionaries/nouns.rtf',encoding="utf8", errors='ignore') as dic:
        #read every line and give it a number
        for line in dic:
            value = line.replace('\\', '')
            key += 1
            d[key] = value
        
    #select a random number in the range of the dictionary (and store it in a variable)
    rand = random.randrange(1, len(d) + 1)

    #get the word with that number (and store it in a variable)
    word = d[rand]

    #print(word)

    return render_template('/player.html', word = word)
```

Javascript

```
<script>
    let is = document.getElementById('innerSpace');
    query = encodeURI({{word}})
    is.src = `https://www.bing.com/images/search?q=weirdest+${query}&form=QBLH&sp=-1&pq=cats&sc=8-4&qs=n&cvid=20659354CDFD49C6B03ED29A4F35EC64&first=1&tsc=ImageBasicHover`
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

To get the randomly generated word from Python to Javascript, you need to return a JSON response from your view.

```
from django.http import JsonResponse

if request.method == 'GET':
    ...
    data = { 'word': word}
    return JsonResponse(data)
```

You can then access the `word` within JavaScript using AJAX or Fetch. I will use Jquery as an example.

```
let is = document.getElementById('innerSpace');
 $.ajax({
        url: '/URL_for_your_view/',
        action: 'GET',
        // when the server returns data, the success method is run
        success: function (data) {
              query = encodeURI({{data.word}})
              is.src = `https://www.bing.com/images/search?q=weirdest+${query}&form=QBLH&sp=-1&pq=cats&sc=8-4&qs=n&cvid=20659354CDFD49C6B03ED29A4F35EC64&first=1&tsc=ImageBasicHover`
        }})
```

Now, the problem with this solution is that the `view` will no longer return the template `player.html` which seems essential in your code.

```
return render_template('/player.html', word = word)
```

To my knowledge, you cannot return a JSON response and a template in the same view. It's impossible.

So you need to use JavaScript to recreate the `player.html` code inside the `success` method and append it to the DOM.